# Video.js with live streaming shows only with autoplay set to true. Can I make it work after clicking play button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, video, video.js

I'm using the [Video.js](http://www.videojs.com/) player to stream live content from my local webcam (but I guess that should not matter in that case, it could be any live stream from web). I wrote a really simple code:

```
<head>
    <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://www.andy-howard.com/js/libs/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
        <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="video1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="480" controls="controls"
        preload="auto" data-setup='{}' autoplay="true" >
        <source src="http://10.172.180.31:8090/live.flv" type="video/x-flv">
    </video>
</body>
```

And now in that configuration I see the stream content, but there are couple errors:

1) I don't see the controls (to pause the stream)

2) Stream looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDWF3.png), so the video is not resized to the full size of the component. BUT (and that's really interesting) when I resize the elements on the webpage (e.g. in Chrome by holding control and scrolling the mouse wheel) to 110%, then the video fills the whole component. Seems like a bug in video.js or maybe my implementation is wrong?

3) when I remove the parameter `autoplay="true"` - nothing shows up, controls and video is gone and it's impossible to play it.

4) I wanted to remove the `autoplay="true"`, but adding the poster info by including `poster="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/NYC_Times_Square_wide_angle.jpg/640px-NYC_Times_Square_wide_angle.jpg"` - nothing has changed, the stream is not visible, the controls are not there.

5) when I remove the `data-setup` parameter and leave it like this:
`<video id="video1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="480" controls="controls"
        preload="auto" poster="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/NYC_Times_Square_wide_angle.jpg/640px-NYC_Times_Square_wide_angle.jpg" >` then the controls and poster are visible (which is great!), but the play button is greyed out and it's impossible to play my stream.

I want to achieve the effect that after loading the webpage I can see the poster image with play button, and when I click it - I will see the properly resized stream. What am I missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try it without the `controls`

This works for me:

```
<video id="se_videojs" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" height="auto" width="auto" data-setup="{}">
<source src="http://server/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegurl">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to use the lastest release of video.js, you are using  3.2 version...

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12.6/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12.6/video.js"></script>
```

Secondly, if you are trying to use a live (stream) with videojs, you should see how videojs reads the stream sources: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/tech.md#enabling-streaming-playback

Note that streaming urls need to have a specific pattern:

```
{protocol}://{your.streaming.provider.net/cfx/st}/{format}:{videoURL}.{format}
```

FLV is a video container, not a protocol, you should use a stream protocol such a RTMP(Flash), HDS(Flash), Mpeg/Dash or HLS(Apple).

Regards,